# Bash fork retry: Resource temporarily unavailable

Tags: bash, loops, fork

I have a simple BASH program that is doing this :

```
max_proc_snmpget=30
getHostnamesFromRouter() {
    while [ `find $proc_dir -name snmpgetproc* | wc -l` -ge "$max_proc_snmpget" ];do
    {
        echo "sleeping, fping in progress";
        sleep 1;
    }
    done

    temp_ip=$($mysql --skip-column-names -h $db_address -u $db_user -p$db_passwd $db_name -e "select ip_routeur,code_site from $db_vtiger_table where $db_vtiger_table.ip_routeur NOT IN (select ip from $db_erreur_table);")
    while read ip codesite;do
    {
        sendSNMPGET $ip $snmp_community $code_site &
    }
    done<<<"$temp_ip"
}

sendSNMPGET() {
    touch $procdir/snmpgetproc.$$
    hostname=`snmpget -v1 -c $2 $1 sysName.0`
    if [ "$hostname" != "" ]
    then
        #$mysql -h $db_address -u $db_user -p$db_passwd $db_name -e "insert into $db_routeur_table (hostname,code_site,ip) VALUES ($hostname,$1,$3);"
        echo "kikou"
    fi
    rm -f $procdir/snmpgetproc.$$
}
```

When started, the program read the 4999 lines from SQL table, then should start a maximum of 30 threads to start the "sendSNMPGET" function.

This is not what is hapenning.

Console gets crazy and send lots of :

```
./scan-snmp.sh: fork: Resource temporarily unavailable
./scan-snmp.sh: fork: Resource temporarily unavailable
./scan-snmp.sh: fork: Resource temporarily unavailable
./scan-snmp.sh: fork: Resource temporarily unavailable
./scan-snmp.sh: fork: Resource temporarily unavailable
./scan-snmp.sh: fork: Resource temporarily unavailable
./scan-snmp.sh: fork: Resource temporarily unavailable
./scan-snmp.sh: fork: Resource temporarily unavailable
kikou
kikou
kikou
kikou
kikou
kikou
```

I have similar functions in others scripts (creating a file for each thread and limiting it with a var) that doesn't have this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Type in 'jobs' at shell prompt.
How many jobs are left over after you previously ran this script?
I am guessing while testing this you have left over jobs after each run of script and after running your script a few times there are too many jobs.

"fork: Resource temporarily unavailable" means you are hitting up against a system limit. I have seen it when out of memory or you could be out of allowed sub-=processes. Type 'ulimit -a' to check the limits.

Also . . . 
There is nothing in your script which limits temp_ip to just 30 entries either?
You maybe could log how big temp_ip is (echo $temp_ip |wc -l).
You could use head -30 or mysql to make sure a max of 30 entries are returned?

```
function testfunc {  echo testfunc;  sleep 30;  echo testfunc END; }
temp_ip="a b
c d
e f
g h
i j
k l
m n
o p
q r
s t
u v
w x
y z
a b
c d
e f
g h
i j
k l
m n
o p
q r
s t
u v
w x
y z
a b
c d
e f
g h"
```

Now repeat this . . . a few times and check 'jobs'.

```
while read ip codesite;do     { echo $ip; testfunc $ip & }
done<<<"$temp_ip"
```

With a process ulimit of 1024 I seem to be able to run this 15 times before trouble starts. I get about 450 jobs in list before trouble.

trouble is like this:

```
-bash: fork: retry: Resource temporarily unavailable
testfunc
-bash: fork: retry: No child processes
testfunc
-bash: fork: retry: No child processes
testfunc
-bash: fork: retry: No child processes
```

Answer (score 0):

I would add a `sleep` to your loop, which should give each fork enough time to finish. Not the most efficient if you're trying to do it very quickly, but if time doesn't matter so much, then this might be your option.